# Regular expression: add string at start and end of line

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have text file and i want to add string for each row at the start and end of line.

for example:

```
BINARY_XML_RECORD_PREFIX_DICTIONARY_ATTRIBUTE_Z
```

After regex action:

```
case BINARY_XML_RECORD_PREFIX_DICTIONARY_ATTRIBUTE_Z:
```

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match:

```
(.+)
```

And replace with:

```
case $1:
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fS3fE1/2)